# What is the drag coefficient of a semi-cylinder travelling at laminar region but with high Reynolds number?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, drag, viscosity, experimental-technique

[image: Open Graph link here]

For Laminar flow along a **cylinder**, the drag coefficient is about **1**.

***Question:***
Can we assume that for Laminar flow along a **semi-cylinder**, the drag coefficient is about **0.5** because the pressure drag dominates greater than frictional drag at laminar region but with high Reynolds number that is just before $10^5$?

Comment: What is the orientation of the semi-cylinder to the flow? Is the curved side or the flat side perpendicular to the flow, or is it at some other angle?

Comment: @Nick curved side perpendicular to flow

Comment: Both cylinder and semi-cylinder

Comment: @MaxsssSu Can you add some picture with flow and semi-cylinder  to show what actually you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The variation of drag coefficient of a semi-circular cylinder with orientation angle is shown below, taken from [Yamagata et al. 2016](https://file.scirp.org/Html/3-2760083_63183.htm#f6). The case you are interested in is $\theta=0$. The measurements were taken at $Re=6.4\times10^4$. Taking the drag coefficient to be $0.5$ is a reasonable approximation.

[image: Drag coefficient plot]

Comment: Sorry @Nick , I mean the flow will pass parallel to the bottom flat side and top curved side of semi-circular cylinder